# how to connect the mysql to laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

It is showing the following error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test1.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `userName` = admin limit 1)

but here is the think that I don't have a table named as `users` my table name is login

here is my login controller code

```
<?php 
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use App\Login;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class LoginController extends Controller {
        public function index(){
            return view('login/login');
        }
        public function show(){
            return view('login/login');
        }

        public function login(){
            $uname = Input::get('username');
            $pwd = Input::get('password');
    //            echo "$uname";
    //            echo "$pwd";
            if (Auth::attempt(array('userName' => $uname, 'password' => $pwd))){
               return Redirect::to('home');

            }
            else {
                return Redirect::to('login');
            }    
         }      
    }
```

my `.env` is as follows

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Zm3uZ82dtjozo68rs2cGAlXXmzj9EuueqCcKsC73VTo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: I recommend the [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017) series it's free and gets you up and running really quickly

Answer (score 2):

> but here is the think is i don't have a table named as **users** my table name is **login**

If your users table name is login, please update your User.php under /app/ and update the user model to use 'login' table

```
protected $table = 'login';
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means: connection to the DB is ok, but we not have table `users` inside `test1` database. So please check `users` table inside `test1` database...

p.s. Laravel ships with several pre-built authentication controllers, you can use it just with `php artisan make:auth`, [read more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authentication-quickstart).

Comment: that is the issue i the datbase i am having a table named as login but it is not taking the value also i am not using laravel pre-bulit authentication